# Making a custom reporter for JSCS results in Gulp4

Tags: gulp, gulp-jscs

Please correct me where I'm wrong (still learning Gulp, Streams, etc.) I'd like to create a custom reporter for my `gulp-jscs` results. For example, let's say I have 3 files in my `gulp.src()` stream. To my knowledge, each is piped one at a time through `jscs`, which attaches a `.jscs` object onto the `file` with its results, one such variable in that object is `.errorCount`.

What I'd like to do is have a variable I create, ie: `maxErrors` which I set to, say `5`. Since we're processing 3 files, let's say the first file passes with 0 errors, but the next has 3 errors. I don't want to prematurely stop processing since the `maxErrors` tally has not been reached (3/5 currently). So it should continue to process the next file which lets say has 3 errors as well, putting us over our max, so that we interrupt `jscs` from continuing to process more files and instead fail out and then let our custom reporter function gain access to the files that have been processed so I can look at their `.jscs` objects and customize some output.

My problem here is that I don't understand the docs when they say: `.pipe(jscs.reporter('name-of-reporter'))` How does a string value invoke my reporter (which currently exists as a function I've imported called `libs.reporters.myJSCSReporter`. I know `pipe()` expects `Stream` objects, so I can't just put a `function` in the `.pipe()` call.

I hope I've explained myself well enough (please ask for clarifications otherwise).